# Transaction (Process ID 72) was deadlocked

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We use a conditional split to split into two, based on a condition from source to two target (both are same table). It was working well before, But now we are facing deadlock issue in this task. the error is as below:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft
>   SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description:
>   "Transaction (Process ID 72) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction

We have setted the properties of OLEDB destination editor with `TABLE LOCK` and maximum insert commit size as `1000000`.

I'm new to SSIS, please help me to resolve this issue!

Here is  the snap of the DATA flow task 
[image]

Comment: What does the deadlock graph say that the related processes are? There may be another player in the mix besides your SSIS package...

Comment: Please help to activate deadlock graph.. im not aware of it

Comment: If you are on at least 2008 you can get the deadlock graph from the default SQL Server extended events session (as long as you check for it reasonably soon after the deadlock was thrown)

Comment: You needn't activate it, you just have to monitor for it. In addition to what Martin Smith said re: extended events, you can view it in SQL Profiler. Create a session with the deadlock graph event and then start your process.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest eliminating one of the destination components (so that you don't have 2 destination components for the same table).  Here are a few suggestions on how to do that:

- Add a **Union All** and have the `Less_than_1` output and the `Less_than_2` outputs go to it.  Then have the **Union All** output go to the destination table
- Analyze the conditions in your **Conditional Split** and see if you can merge them into one (e.g. `ColumnValue is less than 1 OR ColumnValue is less than 2`).  I only suggest this because the data is going to the same table.
- Split the existing data flow into 2 separate **Data Flows** (one for each condition)

Without knowing the specific logic behind your **Conditional Split**, I can't think of any other approaches.

Comment: the split is to make the loading performance better ... just splitting the odd and even rows based on row ID...I have a doubt that Do the lock option in destination come to picture over here on this issue...

Comment: I'm curious, how does the split increase the load performance?

Comment: the rows are splitted into two and loaded in parallel say for eg 50000 records are loaded as 250000 parallely which makes it fast to load into same table. Please check this link... http://henkvandervalk.com/speeding-up-ssis-bulk-inserts-into-sql-server

Comment: Wow, very interesting article and results (+1)!  I tested this approach on ~4 million records and the results were very good.  I will point out though, the article states that the data was loaded to 4 separate tables (see *Step 4) Consolidation* in article).  It may be that the potential for deadlocks is much higher when loading to the same table using this approach instead of separate tables.

Comment: Do unchecking lock condition makes the flow deadlock free ?? i need to know abt the lock check in destination task. Please advice

Comment: Not necessarily.  You could potentially still run into lower-level locks with it turned off.  Why not give it a try and see how it works for you.  Some good information from this Google search --> https://www.google.com/search?q=fastload+tablock+deadlock